# How to change frames for the same object

Tags: unity

Lets say I have four frames A,B,C and D. In idle condition, I want the game object to repeatedly running on frame A and B . When using the method OnMouseDown, the same object change to frame C and D and OnMouseUp it return to the original frame A and B again. I'm not sure what command to look for on the internet. Would appreciate if someone can attach a link or example so I can start learning this myself.

Comment: This sounds like a job for an Animator component, and an animation control graph governing the transitions between these two animations.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will look into to it.